# Send mail to multiple recipients in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I want to send a message to multiple Recipients using following the method:

```
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, String arg1);
```

***Or***

```
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,String arg1);
```

But one confusion is that in the second argument, how to pass multiple addresses like:

```
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, "abc@abc.example,abc@def.example,ghi@abc.example");
```

***Or***
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, "abc@abc.example;abc@def.example;ghi@abc.example");

I can send a message using alternate methods too, but I want to know the purpose of the above method.

If I can’t use it (as till now I haven't got any answer for above requirement) then what is the need for this method to be in mail API.

Comment: Way too many of the answers are "try this" answers without any explanation (e.g., missing the intent (the thinking behind it), the gist, limitations, system tested on (incl. versions), etc.) and they have very little value. What if they don't work for some reason (e.g., due to version dependencies or a particular context)? If you are going to add a new answer, please don't just dump some code without explanation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [The Help Center says](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*.

Answer (score 132):

If you invoke `addRecipient` multiple times, it will add the given recipient to the list of recipients of the given time (TO, [CC](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/carbon_copy#Noun), and [BCC](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blind_carbon_copy#English)).

For example:

```
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse("abc@abc.example"));
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse("abc@def.example"));
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse("ghi@abc.example"));
```

It will add the three addresses to CC.

---

If you wish to add all addresses at once, you should use `setRecipients` or `addRecipients` and provide it with an array of addresses

```
Address[] cc = new Address[] {InternetAddress.parse("abc@abc.example"),
                               InternetAddress.parse("abc@def.example"),
                               InternetAddress.parse("ghi@abc.example")};
message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, cc);
```

---

You can also use `InternetAddress.parse` to parse a list of addresses:

```
message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC,
                      InternetAddress.parse("abc@abc.example,abc@def.example,ghi@abc.example"));
```

Comment: So i have to use it n times for n recipients than what is the use of tis overloaded method....then second arguement as an Array is better.please suggest

Comment: Actually my question is specifically regarding a particular method.

Comment: you either use `addRecipient`/`setRecipient` with a single address or `addRecipients`/`setRecipients` with an array of addresses

Comment: please see docs of MimeMessage class there u find the method specified in my question. i want to know how to use that method

Comment: Is this what you wanted ? parse the comma separated list of addresses ?

Comment: again your answer is missing the same thing,see the api u used dear. i searchrd a lot but till yet not get the answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21052/discussion-between-aviram-segal-and-prateek)

Comment: `javax.mail` version 1.5.5 doesn't have `InternetAddress.parse()` that returns `String`.  All parse methods return array and so are not suitable for `addRecipient`. Is there other version (s) that has such method?

Comment: When you have `javax.mail` version `1.5.5` or greater where you don't have `InternetAddress.parse()` that returns single `InternetAddress` but only the one that returns `InternetAddress[]` (array) you can use the **the first solution** having  `... message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse("abc@def.com")[0]); ...` **([0] is important there)**. In **the second solution:** `... new Address[] {InternetAddress.parse("abc@abc.com")[0], ...` **The third solution** should work without changes. Of course **[0]** at the end should be applied to all addresses in each solution.

Comment: @luke.. thanks, I have been struggling for a while.. and your comment helped me.

Comment: Instead of Message.RecipientType.CC use javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.CC

Answer (score 29):

This code is working for me. Please try with this for sending mail to multiple recipients

```
private String recipient = "yamabs@gmail.com ,priya@gmail.com ";
String[] recipientList = recipient.split(",");
InternetAddress[] recipientAddress = new InternetAddress[recipientList.length];
int counter = 0;
for (String recipient : recipientList) {
    recipientAddress[counter] = new InternetAddress(recipient.trim());
    counter++;
}
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, recipientAddress);
```

Answer (score 19):

Just use the method message.setRecipients with multiple addresses separated by commas:

```
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("abc@abc.example,abc@def.com,ghi@abc.example"));

message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse("abc@abc.example,abc@def.com,ghi@abc.example"));
```

It works fine with only one address too:

```
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("abc@abc.example"));
```

Answer (score 11):

You can have multiple addresses separated by comma

```
if (cc.indexOf(',') > 0)
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(cc));   
else
    message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(cc));
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `InternetAddress.parse()` for both? (And yes, I know this is 4 years old)

Comment: @seanbright  yes you can just have the first statement skipping the if else condition altogether. `setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(cc));` should work even if there's only 1 address. It's a just a personal way of programming to increase readability.

Answer (score 11):

Try this way:

```
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("mail3@mail.example"));
String address = "mail@mail.example,mail2@mail.example";
InternetAddress[] iAdressArray = InternetAddress.parse(address);
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, iAdressArray);
```

Answer (score 7):

Internet E-mail address format ([RFC 822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt?number=822)):

> `(,)`comma separated sequence of addresses

javax.mail - 1.4.7 `parse(String[])` is not allowed. So we have to give a comma-separated sequence of addresses into [`InternetAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html) objects. Addresses must follow the RFC822 syntax.

```
String toAddress = "mail@mail.example,mail2@mail.example";
InternetAddress.parse(toAddress);
```

> `(;)` semi-colon separated sequence of addresses «
> If [a group of address list](http://jkorpela.fi/rfc/822addr.html) is provided with delimiter as ";", then convert to a string array using the *split* method to use the following function.

```java
String[] addressList = { "mail@mail.example", "mail2@mail.example" };

String toGroup = "mail@mail.example;mail2@mail.example";
String[] addressList2 = toGroup.split(";");

setRecipients(message, addressList);
```

```java
public static void setRecipients(Message message, Object addresslist) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
    if (addresslist instanceof String) { // CharSequence
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse((String) addresslist));
    } else if (addresslist instanceof String[]) { // String[] « Array with collection of Strings/
        String[] toAddressList = (String[]) addresslist;
        InternetAddress[] mailAddress_TO = new InternetAddress[ toAddressList.length ];
        for (int i = 0; i < toAddressList.length; i++) {
            mailAddress_TO[i] = new InternetAddress(toAddressList[i]);
        }
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, mailAddress_TO);
    }
}
```

#### Full example

```java
public static Properties getMailProperties(boolean addExteraProps) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", MAIL_TRNSPORT_PROTOCOL);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", MAIL_SERVER_NAME);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", MAIL_PORT);

    // Sending Email to the GMail SMTP server requires authentication and SSL.
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
    if(ENCRYPTION_METHOD.equals("STARTTLS")) {
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", SMTP_STARTTLS_PORT); // 587
    } else {
        props.put("mail.smtps.ssl.enable", true);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", SMTP_SSL_PORT); // 465
    }
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory", SOCKETFACTORY_CLASS);
    return props;
}

public static boolean sendMail(String subject, String contentType, String msg, Object recipients) throws Exception {

    Properties props = getMailProperties(false);
    Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    mailSession.setDebug(true);

    Message message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(USER_NAME));

    setRecipients(message, recipients);

    message.setSubject(subject);

    String htmlData = "<h1>This is actual message embedded in HTML tags</h1>";
    message.setContent(htmlData, "text/html");

    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport(MAIL_TRNSPORT_PROTOCOL);
    transport.connect(MAIL_SERVER_NAME, Integer.valueOf(MAIL_PORT), USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
    message.saveChanges(); // Don't forget this

    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
}
```

---

> Using Appache `SimpleEmail` - `commons-email-1.3.1`

Example: `email.addTo(addressList);`

```java
public static void sendSimpleMail() throws Exception {
    Email email = new SimpleEmail();
    email.setSmtpPort(587);

    DefaultAuthenticator defaultAuthenticator = new DefaultAuthenticator(USER_NAME, PASSWORD);

    email.setAuthenticator(defaultAuthenticator);
    email.setDebug(false);
    email.setHostName(MAIL_SERVER_NAME);
    email.setFrom(USER_NAME);
    email.setSubject("Hi");
    email.setMsg("This is a test mail... :-)");

    //email.addTo("mail@mail.example", "Yash");
    String[] toAddressList = { "mail@mail.example", "mail2@mail.example" }
    email.addTo(addressList);

    email.setTLS(true);
    email.setStartTLSEnabled(true);
    email.send();
    System.out.println("Mail sent!");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

So ... it took many months, but still ... You can send email to multiple recipients by using the  ',' as separator and

```
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, "abc@abc.example,abc@def.example,ghi@abc.example");
```

is OK. At least in JavaMail 1.4.5

Answer (score 6):

InternetAddress.Parse is going to be your friend! See the worked example below:

```
String to = "med@joe.example, maz@frank.example, jezz@jam.example";
String toCommaAndSpaces = "med@joe.example maz@frank.example, jezz@jam.example";
```

1. Parse a comma-separated list of email addresses. Be strict. Require comma separated list.
2. If strict is true, many (but not all) of the [RFC822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt?number=822) syntax rules for emails are enforced.

   ```
   msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC,
   InternetAddress.parse(to, true));
   ```
3. Parse comma/space-separated list. Cut some slack. We allow spaces seperated list as well, plus invalid email formats.

   ```
   msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC,
   InternetAddress.parse(toCommaAndSpaces, false));
   ```

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] mailAddressTo = new String[3];    
mailAddressTo[0] = emailId_1;    
mailAddressTo[1] = emailId_2;    
mailAddressTo[2] = "xyz@gmail.com";

InternetAddress[] mailAddress_TO = new InternetAddress[mailAddressTo.length];

for (int i = 0; i < mailAddressTo.length; i++)
{
    mailAddress_TO[i] = new InternetAddress(mailAddressTo[i]);
}

message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, mailAddress_TO);ress_TO = new InternetAddress[mailAddressTo.length];
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do it:

```
String[] listofIDS = {"ramasamygms@gmail.com", "ramasamycse94@gmail.com"};
        
for(String cc:listofIDS) {
    message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(cc));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use n number of recipients with the below method:

```
String to[] = {"a@gmail.com"} // Mail ID you want to send;
InternetAddress[] address = new InternetAddress[to.length];
for(int i=0; i< to.length; i++)
{
    address[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
}

msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
```

Comment: i specified a particular method in my question, want to send using that.

Comment: @Dhinkar, how to send mail to all subscribers with java?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send as [CC](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/carbon_copy#Noun) using MimeMessageHelper:

```
List<String> emails = new ArrayList();
email.add("email1");
email.add("email2");

for (String string : emails) {
    message.addCc(string);
}
```

In the same way, you can use to add multiple recipients.