# I need to send mail for multiple recipients

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

In my application, i need to send mail for multiple recipients but i can able to send only one recipient. I try using semi colon that also wont work. I tried but i didnt get any solution, if anyone know about this please make me to know about that.Hope someone will help me to find.

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

@WebServlet("/SendMailAttachServlet")
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024 * 2,   // 2MB
                maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10,         // 10MB
                maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 50)      // 50MB
public class SendMailAttachServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private String host;
    private String port;

    public void init() {
        // reads SMTP server setting from web.xml file
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
       // host = context.getInitParameter("host");
        port = context.getInitParameter("port");
    }

    /**
     * handles form submission
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        List<File> uploadedFiles = saveUploadedFiles(request);
         host="smtp.gmail.com";
         port="587";
        String user = request.getParameter("Sender");
        String pass = request.getParameter("Password");
        String recipient = request.getParameter("recipient");

        System.out.println(recipient);
        String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
        String content = request.getParameter("content");

        String resultMessage = "";

        try {
            EmailUtility.sendEmailWithAttachment(host, port, user, pass,
                    recipient, subject, content, uploadedFiles);

            resultMessage = "The e-mail was sent successfully";
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            resultMessage = "There were an error: " + ex.getMessage();
        } finally {
            deleteUploadFiles(uploadedFiles);
            request.setAttribute("message", resultMessage);
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Result.jsp").forward(
                    request, response);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Saves files uploaded from the client and return a list of these files
     * which will be attached to the e-mail message.
     */
    private List<File> saveUploadedFiles(HttpServletRequest request)
            throws IllegalStateException, IOException, ServletException {
        List<File> listFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        Collection<Part> multiparts = request.getParts();
        if (multiparts.size() > 0) {
            for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
                // creates a file to be saved
                String fileName = extractFileName(part);
                if (fileName == null || fileName.equals("")) {
                    // not attachment part, continue
                    continue;
                }

                File saveFile = new File(fileName);
                System.out.println("saveFile: " + saveFile.getAbsolutePath());
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);

                // saves uploaded file
                InputStream inputStream = part.getInputStream();
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();

                listFiles.add(saveFile);
            }
        }
        return listFiles;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves file name of a upload part from its HTTP header
     */
    private String extractFileName(Part part) {
        String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
        String[] items = contentDisp.split(";");
        for (String s : items) {
            if (s.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
                return s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 2, s.length() - 1);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Deletes all uploaded files, should be called after the e-mail was sent.
     */
    private void deleteUploadFiles(List<File> listFiles) {
        if (listFiles != null && listFiles.size() > 0) {
            for (File aFile : listFiles) {
                aFile.delete();
            }
        }
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
            {

            }

}
```

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854037/send-mail-to-multiple-recipients-in-java).  This question has been answered already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
transport = mailSession.getNewTransport(session);
String to = "mail1@gmail.com , mail2@gmail.com, mail3@gmail.com";
InternetAddress[] parse = InternetAddress.parse(to , true);
message.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,  parse);
transport.send(message);
```

Thanks 
Raaghu.K

Comment: Or just use the addRecipients method.  (Does anyone read javadocs anymore?)

Answer (score 0):

Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

```
        if (toList.size() > 0) {
            for (String to : toList) {
                if (!SessionUtil.isStringEmpty(to)) {
                    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: **message. addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));**