# Sending multiple email over javax.mail

Tags: java, mailx

I am trying to send multiple mails using JAVA Mail -

When I add a single Recipient -

```
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(“abc@xyz.com”));
```

It works fine, but not when I add multiple email addresses -

Here is the code

```
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(“abc@xyz.com”));
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(“def@xyz.com"));

message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(“ghi@xyz.com"));
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(“jkl@xyz.com"));

message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(“mno@xyz.com"));
```

The mail is sent and received, but when I check the email of `abc@xyz.com` I can't see that the email has also been sent to `def@xyz.com` or vise versa. Neither I can see CC in the list.

Mail details from abc@xyz.com

```
from:   xyz@xyz.com
to: abc@xyz.com
date:   Thu, Sep 8, 2016 at 4:38 PM
subject:    Test
```

Mail details from def@xyz.com

```
from:   xyz@xyz.com
to: def@xyz.com
date:   Thu, Sep 8, 2016 at 4:38 PM
subject:    Test
```

Mail details from ghi@xyz.com

```
from:   xyz@xyz.com
to: ghi@xyz.com
date:   Thu, Sep 8, 2016 at 4:38 PM
subject:    Test
```

Mail details from jkl@xyz.com

```
from:   xyz@xyz.com
to: jkl@xyz.com
date:   Thu, Sep 8, 2016 at 4:38 PM
subject:    Test
```

I tried changing the logic a little, but same result -

```
message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(“abc@xyz.com, def@xyz.com"));

message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(“ghi@xyz.com, jkl@xyz.com”));

message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, InternetAddress.parse(“mno@xyz.com"));
```

I am expecting to see the details as -

```
from:   xyz@xyz.com
to: abc@xyz.com, def@xyz.com
cc: ghi@xyz.com, jkl@xyz.com
date:   Thu, Sep 8, 2016 at 4:38 PM
subject:    Test
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854037/send-mail-to-multiple-recipients-in-java Also note that there is some "quote" issue in your posted code (`“` vs `"`)

Comment: Please avoid the quote, its actually  "

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
Address[] toArray = new Address[] {InternetAddress.parse("abc@xyz.com"),
                               InternetAddress.parse("def@xyz.com")};
message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toArray);
```

Comment: I tried this - `Address[] mail_To = new Address[] {new InternetAddress("abc@xyz.com"), new InternetAddress("efg@xyz.com")};
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, mail_To);` It didn't work. I am receiving individual mails, can't see who all are in the list

Answer (score 1):

To prevent any mistakes and surprises, I would recommend to use [`setRecipients(Message.RecipientType type, Address[] addresses)`](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Message.html#setRecipients-javax.mail.Message.RecipientType-javax.mail.Address:A-) as next:

```
message.setRecipients(
    Message.RecipientType.TO, 
    new Address[]{new InternetAddress("abc@xyz.com"), new InternetAddress("def@xyz.com")}
);
```

Comment: I tried this - `Address[] mail_To = new Address[] {new InternetAddress("abc@xyz.com"), new InternetAddress("efg@xyz.com")}; message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, mail_To);` It didn't work. I am receiving individual mails, can't see who all are in the list

Comment: I use the exact same code on my project, and I see properly all the addresses in the TO' section, you problem is elsewhere maybe it is related to your SMTP server?

Comment: I am using mandrillapp.com, and also i tried using gmail user, still the same

Comment: I use gmail too in my project and I send emails to multiple recipients with this code and I see all the  recipients in the email received so I don't know what to add