# How to send email to multiple receiptent using java mail api in android?

Tags: android

I have an app in which i am sending email using JAVA mail API, here i am only send mail to one recipient, but want to send a copy to other.Is it possible to do that using java mail API.How can i do that

code:-

```
//Declaring Variables
private Context context;
private Session session;

//Information to send email
private String email;
private String subject;
private String message;

//Progressdialog to show while sending email
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

//Class Constructor
public SendMail(Context context, String email, String subject, String message){
    //Initializing variables
    this.context = context;
    this.email = email;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.message = message;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    //Showing progress dialog while sending email
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Sending message","Please wait...",false,false);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    //Dismissing the progress dialog
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    //Showing a success message
    Toast.makeText(context,"Message Sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //Creating properties
    Properties props = new Properties();

    //Configuring properties for gmail
    //If you are not using gmail you may need to change the values
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "cp-19.webhostbox.net");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    //Creating a new session
    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                //Authenticating the password
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(Config.EMAIL, Config.PASSWORD);
                }
            });

    try {
        //Creating MimeMessage object
        MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);

        //Setting sender address
        mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Config.EMAIL));
        //Adding receiver
        mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));

        //Adding subject
        mm.setSubject(subject);
        //Adding message
        mm.setText(message);

        //Sending email
        Transport.send(mm);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

MainActivity code

```
    //Initializing the views
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSubject);
    editTextMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);

    buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);

    //Adding click listener
    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(this);
}


private void sendEmail() {
    //Getting content for email
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String subject = editTextSubject.getText().toString().trim();
    String message = editTextMessage.getText().toString().trim();

    //Creating SendMail object
    SendMail sm = new SendMail(this, email, subject, message);

    //Executing sendmail to send email
    sm.execute();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    sendEmail();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you invoke addRecipient multiple times it will add the given recipient to the list of recipients of the given time (TO, CC, BCC)

For example:

```
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse("abc@abc.com"));
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse("abc@def.com"));
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse("ghi@abc.com"))
```

[Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13854096/5545429)

Answer (score 0):

Use InternetAddress.parse to parse a list of addresses

```
message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
InternetAddress.parse("abc@abc.com,abc@def.com,ghi@abc.com"));
```